# How to display an incremental identity value that's been persisted in a database

Tags: c#

I want to display the latest incremental identity value in a textbox.

The problem isn't when the program is running, but when restart it (the value goes back to 101).

Any idea?

```
    static int trid = 100;
    static int batchNo = 0;


    public StartInspection()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Fillcombo();
        try
        {
            _capture = new Capture(0);
            _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
        }

    }
    public static string SetValueForText = "";

    void Fillcombo()
    {
        String constring = "Data Source=JECKDGREAT\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TileDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=jeric;Password=jericpogi";
        String query = "Select * from addNewTileModel";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataReader m_dr;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            m_dr = command.ExecuteReader();


            while (m_dr.Read())
            {
                String sName = m_dr["prodCode"].ToString();
                cmbTileModI.Items.Add(sName);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();

        Image<Gray, Byte> grayFrame = frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
        Image<Gray, Byte> smallGrayFrame = grayFrame.PyrDown();
        Image<Gray, Byte> smoothedGrayFrame = smallGrayFrame.PyrUp();
        Image<Gray, Byte> cannyFrame = smoothedGrayFrame.Canny(100, 60);

        imageBox1.Image = frame;
        grayscaleImageBox.Image = grayFrame;
        //smoothedGrayscaleImageBox.Image = smoothedGrayFrame;
        imageBox2.Image = cannyFrame;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void captureButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_capture != null)
        {
            if (_captureInProgress)
            {  //start the capture
                captureButton.Text = "Start Capture";
                _capture.Pause();
            }
            else
            {
                //stop the capture
                captureButton.Text = "Stop";
                _capture.Start();
            }

            _captureInProgress = !_captureInProgress;
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseData()
    {
        if (_capture != null)
            _capture.Dispose();
    }


    private void captureImageBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void StartInspection_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        batchNo = batchNo + 1;
        txtBatchNumI.Text = batchNo.ToString();

        trid = trid + 1;
        txtTestRepIDI.Text = trid.ToString();
    }

    private void lineShape3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _capture.Pause();
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_capture != null) _capture.FlipHorizontal = !_capture.FlipHorizontal;
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _capture.Stop();
        imageBox1.Image = null;
        imageBox2.Image = null;
    }


    private void cmbTileModI_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String constring = "Data Source=JECKDGREAT\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TileDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=jeric;Password=jericpogi";
        String query = "Select * from addNewTileModel where prodCode= '" + cmbTileModI.Text + "' ;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataReader m_dr;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            m_dr = command.ExecuteReader();


            while (m_dr.Read())
            {
                String sProdCode = m_dr["prodCode"].ToString();
                String sDescProd = m_dr["descProd"].ToString();
                String sCeramicType = m_dr["ceramicType"].ToString();
                String sClassification = m_dr["classification"].ToString();
                String sCollection = m_dr["collection"].ToString();
                String sColorFamily = m_dr["colorFamily"].ToString();
                String sTileSize = m_dr["tileSize"].ToString();
                String sThickness = m_dr["thickness"].ToString();
                String sBendingStr = m_dr["bendingStr"].ToString();
                String sPorosity = m_dr["porosity"].ToString();
                String sChemicalRes = m_dr["chemicalRes"].ToString();
                String sWarpage = m_dr["warpage"].ToString();
                //Image sTileImage = (Byte [])m_dr["imageTile"];

                textBox1.Text = sProdCode;
                textBox2.Text = sDescProd;
                textBox3.Text = sCeramicType;
                textBox4.Text = sClassification;
                textBox5.Text = sCollection;
                textBox6.Text = sColorFamily;
                textBox7.Text = sTileSize;
                textBox8.Text = sThickness;
                textBox9.Text = sBendingStr;
                textBox10.Text = sPorosity;
                textBox11.Text = sChemicalRes;
                textBox12.Text = sWarpage;
                //pictureBox1.Image = sTileImage;

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //String constring = "Data Source=JECKDGREAT\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TileDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=jeric;Password=jericpogi";
        //String query = "Insert into testReport5" + "(testReportID, inspectionDate, inspectedBy, batchNumber, prodCode, descProd, ceramicType, classification, collection, colorFamily, tileSize, thickness, bendingStr, porosity, chemicalRes, warpage, tileImage)"
        //    + "Values('" + txtTestRepIDI.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "', '" + txtInsByI.Text + "', '" + txtBatchNumI.Text + "', '" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + textBox5.Text + "', '" + textBox6.Text + "', '" + textBox7.Text + "', '" + textBox8.Text + "', '" + textBox9.Text + "', '" + textBox10.Text + "', '" + textBox11.Text + "', '" + textBox12.Text + "', '" + pictureBox1.Image + "')";
        //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
        //SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        //SqlDataReader m_dr;
        //try
        //{
        //    conn.Open();
        //    m_dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        //    MessageBox.Show("Status Saved");
        //    while (m_dr.Read())
        //    {

        //    }
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        //}
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var capture = new Emgu.CV.Capture();

        using (var ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame())
        {
            if (ImageFrame != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
                ImageFrame.Save(@"C:\Users\crowds\Documents\Example\Sample.jpg");
            }
            _capture.Dispose();

        }            
        //String constring = "Data Source=JECKDGREAT\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TileDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=jeric;Password=jericpogi";
        //String query = "Insert into imageTable" + " (tileImage)" + "Values('" + pictureBox1.Image + "')";
        //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
        //SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        //SqlDataReader m_dr;
        //var capture = new Emgu.CV.Capture();

        //try
        //{
        //    conn.Open();
        //    m_dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        //    MessageBox.Show("Status Saved");

        //    using (var ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame())
        //    {
        //        if (ImageFrame != null)
        //        {
        //            pictureBox1.Image = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
        //            //ImageFrame.Save(@"C:\Users\crowds\Documents\Example\Sample.jpg");
        //            //ImageFrame.Save(@"Insert into testReport1" + "(tileImage)");
        //        }
        //        _capture.Dispose();
        //    }
        //    while (m_dr.Read())
        //    {

        //    }
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        //}
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (_capture != null)
        {
            //SetValueForText = cmbTileModI.Text;

            //StartCompare FF = new StartCompare();
            FF.fa = cmbTileModI.Text;
            FF.fb = txtBatchNumI.Text;
            FF.fc = dateTimePicker1.Text;
            FF.fd = txtTestRepIDI.Text;
            FF.fe = txtInsByI.Text;

            this.Hide();
            FF.Show();
            _capture.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtBatchNumI_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }




}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You declare and initialise `trid` to 100 at the top of your code example;

```
static int trid = 100;
```

Nowhere in your example are you then setting its value to anything returned from your database query.

If you are storing the `increment` value in your database, you need to obtain the value using a query and then assign the value to `trid` before you use it.

If you are not storing the `increment` value in your database, you could use the number of rows returned in a query as an `increment` value and assign that to `trid`.